# What preposition to be used in "student ? [field of study]"?

Tags: prepositions

I want to introduce myself as a physics student, but I don't know which preposition is appropriate.

Which one is correct:

- "Undergraduate/MSc Student **in** Physics"
- "Undergraduate/MSc Student **of** Physics"
- "Undergraduate/MSc Physics Student"

Answer (score 1):

You should really just use a dictionary.

physics
noun [ U ]
UK  /ˈfɪzɪks/ US

the scientific study of matter and energy:
**He studied Physics at university** before becoming an engineer.
a physics lab/researcher/degree

From here it is not a big jump to

**"Undergraduate/MSc Physics Student"**

---

**of** does not work when Physics comes before student

of preposition (POSSESSION)(AMOUNT)(CONTAINING)(POSITION)(TYPICAL)(DAYS)(MADE OF)(WITH ADJECTIVES/VERBS); used to connect particular adjectives and verbs with nouns:(JUDGMENT)(RELATING TO)(THAT IS/ARE)(DONE TO)(FELT BY)(THROUGH(COMPARING)

At a stretch you could try using (THAT IS/ARE)

**"Undergraduate/MSc (that is a) Physics, Student"** but it does not sound right in either the of or that is form.

If you wanted to use "of" then I am an **Undergraduate/MSc Student of Physics** is more appropriate or alternatively **I am studying Physics for my MSc****

---

**In** does not work with either student before or after Physics

of preposition (TIME)(INSIDE)(INTO)(DURING)(NO MORE THAN)(BEFORE THE END)(EXPERIENCING)(EXPRESSED)(RESULT)(ARRANGEMENT)(AGE/TEMPERATURE)(INVOLVED)(WEARING)(COMPARING AMOUNTS)
(CHARACTERISTIC)(CAUSE)

All Ref CED [Physics](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/physics?q=)

Comment: "Undergraduate Student of Physics", "BSc Student of Physics", "Undergraduate Physics Student" or "BSc Physics Student", which one is more frequently used?

Answer (score 1):

Any one of

> Undergraduate student of Physics
> BSc student of Physics
> Undergraduate Physics student
> BSc Physics student

would work and are more or less indistinguishable

> Undergraduate (or BSc) MSc Student in Physics

is not correct. You would say that someone obtained a degree in Physics but that is a different construction.